# Matter recommended SoCs

Tags: smart-home, matter

I'm working on climate control smart home thingy. The setup includes ~100 sensors and ~20 relays, currently operated by a python program on a Raspberry Pi, communicating over BLE with ESP32 boards that are connected to sensors/relays.

I want to make the setup work with Matter over Thread (as I have too many BLE devices there are too many connectivity issues). I considered BLE Mesh, but since it's a big change anyway, I thought of replacing the ESP32 with Matter/Thread supporting SoCs.

I'm considering development boards with Nordic's nRF5340 vs Silicon Labs' EFR32MG24. ESP32-H2 would be ideal if it would be released already, as I already know how to connect it to 1-wire/I2C/gpio etc. Does anyone have experience with any of these? And knows which one is easiest to use for prototyping? Other options I missed? Other considerations before choosing a SoC for my project?

Comment: Not a recommendation because it’s just been released and support seems quite incomplete for now, but something to keep in mind: https://www.cnx-software.com/2023/01/12/esp32-c6-wifi-6-ble-802-15-4-module-development-board/

Comment: Considering Matter 1.0 is only out for out for a few months there's not too many people out there (who are not from involved companies) with a lot of experience yet. The chip companies like NXP  sell their stuff of course (cf. https://www.nxp.com/products/wireless/multiprotocol-mcus/end-node-matter-with-thread-development-platform:END-NODE-MATTER-THREAD)